# WPF thumbnail image is blurry

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **WPF** app which saves out a thumbnail image as **png**. The code works well enough but when I open the image is very blurry. The image that it grabs comes from the canvas itself. The canvas changes its width and height depending on the image I'm loading. The desired thumbnail size will be **200 x 200** (*pixels*).

Here is my code

```
    public void CreateThumbail(Canvas canvas, string filename)
    {
      RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)canvas.ActualWidth,
        (int)canvas.ActualHeight,
        96, //dip X
        96, //dpi Y
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
      rtb.Render(canvas);

      PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();

      pngImage.Frames.Add(CreateResizedImage(rtb, 200, 200, 0));
      using (var filestream = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
      {
        pngImage.Save(filestream);
      }
    }

    private static BitmapFrame CreateResizedImage(ImageSource source, int width, int height, int margin)
    {
      var rect = new Rect(margin, margin, width, height);

      var group = new DrawingGroup();
      RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(group, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
      group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(source, rect));

      var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
      using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        drawingContext.DrawDrawing(group);

      var resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(
          (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height,// Resized dimensions
          96, 96, // Default DPI values
          PixelFormats.Pbgra32); // Default pixel format
      resizedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

      return BitmapFrame.Create(resizedImage);
    }
```

I saved out the image before I resize it and it looks crisp and sharp. yet when I save out the thumbnail it's ugly and blurry. What am I doing wrong? Am I over-engineering this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to respect the original dimensions of the image. For instance an image that is 400x400 will downscale to 200x200 quite nicely, but an image that is 235x235 will not.

This doesn't consider images that are not square to begin with.

You might try reducing the image height and width by a good factor (I would start by halving) repeatedly until the image is smaller than 200x200 and then padding it with white or transparent.

Image processing can be quite hard. It's not something I'm an expert in either so I'd probably try a 3rd party library like this one I just found on google: https://imageprocessor.org/